# Code optimization

Tags: ubuntu, python

Below I'll show a part of my code (a method I've created) and I would like to ask what would be your suggestions to improve the readability and make it more beautiful.

So, what I do is I do read an excel file and based on **DISPLAY** column I do execute some queries in DB. But my problem is the ternary operator which is heavily used and looks very bad.

```
def add_new_patient_identifier(self, excel_file, sheet):

    patient_identifiers = self.excel_reader.read_excel_sheet(excel_file, sheet)
    header = self.excel_reader.get_header(patient_identifiers)

    self.openmrsclient_db.execute("DELETE FROM  idgen_identifier_source")
    self.openmrsclient_db.execute("DELETE FROM  idgen_seq_id_gen")

    for identifier in patient_identifiers.iter_rows(min_row=2):
        if identifier[header['Display']].value == "Yes":

            field = str(identifier[header['Field']].value) if str(identifier[header['Field']].value) != 'None' else ''
            description = str(identifier[header['Source Description']].value) if str(identifier[header['Source Description']].value) != 'None' else ''
            next_sequence_value = str(identifier[header['Next Sequence Value']].value) if str(identifier[header['Next Sequence Value']].value) != 'None' else ''
            base_character_set = str(identifier[header['Base Character Set']].value) if str(identifier[header['Base Character Set']].value) != 'None' else ''
            first_identifier_base = str(identifier[header['First Identifier Base']].value) if str(identifier[header['First Identifier Base']].value) != 'None' else ''
            suffix = str(identifier[header['Suffix']].value) if str(identifier[header['Suffix']].value) != 'None' else ''
            min_length = str(identifier[header['Min Length']].value) if str(identifier[header['Min Length']].value) != 'None' else ''
            max_length = str(identifier[header['Max Length']].value) if str(identifier[header['Max Length']].value) != 'None' else ''
            type_identifier = str(identifier[header['Type']].value) if str(identifier[header['Type']].value) != 'None' else ''

            identifier_type_id = str(self.openmrsclient_db.fetch(
                "SELECT patient_identifier_type_id FROM patient_identifier_type WHERE name = '" + type_identifier + "'")[0][0])

            self.openmrsclient_db.execute("INSERT INTO idgen_identifier_source (uuid, name, description, identifier_type, date_created, creator) \
                            VALUES (uuid(),'" + field + "', '" + description + "', '" + identifier_type_id + "', now(), '1')")

            identifier_source_id = str(self.openmrsclient_db.fetch("SELECT id FROM idgen_identifier_source WHERE name = '" + field + "'")[0][0])

            self.openmrsclient_db.execute("INSERT INTO idgen_seq_id_gen (id, next_sequence_value, base_character_set, first_identifier_base, prefix, suffix, min_length, max_length) \
                            VALUES (" + identifier_source_id + "," + next_sequence_value + "," + base_character_set+","+first_identifier_base+",'" +
                                          field+"','"+suffix+"'," + min_length + "," + max_length + ")")
```

Comment: This query would have been more suited for the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site, or possibly at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) as it's a programming question rather than a question about Unix or Linux.

Comment: I did not ask for queries, I asked for improving readability. 
Thanks

Comment: What Kusalandra is trying to say is that this question is better to ask on Code Review.  Code Review helps with code readability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say, start off by not converting twice:

```
field = str(identifier[header['Field']].value)
field = '' if field == 'None' else field
```

You might put that ternary and accessors in a separate function:

```
def load(identifier, header, field):
    val = str(identifier[header[field]].value)
    rval = '' if val == 'None' else rval

field = load(identifier, header, 'Field')
description = load(identifier, header, 'Source Description')
```

etc.

Also, about those SQL statements: what you are doing there is ripe for SQL injection. If the openmrsclient_db supports prepared statements, I strongly recommend you use them.

For example, if someone put something like "0); DROP TABLE idgen_seq_id_gen" for "max_length", the database may happily delete that table. I admit I've never used openmrsclient_db but it is likely susceptible to SQL injection when used with unsanitized inputs.

Comment: I do appreciate your comment a lot.
Thank you Chris

Answer (score -1):

So, this is what I managed to do with variables only (since the queries are not priority now)

```
def add_new_patient_identifier(self, excel_file, sheet):

    patient_identifiers = self.excel_reader.read_excel_sheet(excel_file, sheet)
    header = self.excel_reader.get_header(patient_identifiers)

    self.openmrsclient_db.execute("DELETE FROM  idgen_identifier_source")
    self.openmrsclient_db.execute("DELETE FROM  idgen_seq_id_gen")

    for identifier in patient_identifiers.iter_rows(min_row=2):
        if self.load(identifier, header, 'Display') == "Yes":

            field = self.load(identifier, header, 'Field')
            description = self.load(identifier, header, 'Source Description')
            next_sequence_value = self.load(identifier, header, 'Next Sequence Value')
            base_character_set = self.load(identifier, header, 'Base Character Set')
            first_identifier_base = self.load(identifier, header, 'First Identifier Base')
            suffix = self.load(identifier, header, 'Suffix')
            min_length = self.load(identifier, header, 'Min Length')
            max_length = self.load(identifier, header, 'Max Length')
            type_identifier = self.load(identifier, header, 'Type')


def load(self, key, header, field):
        original_cell_value = key[header[field]].value
        cell_value = '' if original_cell_value == 'None' else original_cell_value
        return str(cell_value)
```